# Placing a JS variable into an e-mailed HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-table

So, I am trying to place some calculated data into an HTML table, but currently I can't seem to get it to populate properly. All my google script, when logged out, seems to be generating the proper values.

When logged out, my HTML seems to be generating properly.

When tested with some dummy data, my table seemed to populate properly: https://codepen.io/TommyJay337/pen/oNQpePJ

I can't seem to place them into my table when developing in Google's environment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ILdr_rkCtEedOtUTzG8_Sq6bvIW3RVs63Z1tiZbpZKI/edit?usp=sharing

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weekly Stats</title>
    <base target="_top">
    <style> ...
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Here are your stats:</p>
    <table class="styled-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Lift</th>
                <th>e1RM</th>
                <th>Tonnage</th>
                <th>Avg Intensity (RPE)</th>
                <th>Total Sets</th>
                <th>Total Reps</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Squat</td>
                <td id="e1RMCell">-</td>
                <td id="tonnageCell">-</td>
                <td id="avgIntensityCell">-</td>
                <td id="totalSetsCell">-</td>
                <td id="totalRepsCell">-</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Nice job!</p>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateTable).emailTableData();
        });

      function updateTable(stats) {
        document.getElementById("e1RMCell").textContent = stats.e1RM;
        document.getElementById("tonnageCell").textContent = stats.tonnage;
        document.getElementById("avgIntensityCell").textContent = stats.avgIntensity;
        document.getElementById("totalSetsCell").textContent = stats.totalSets;
        document.getElementById("totalRepsCell").textContent = stats.totalReps;
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

GS file:

```
function emailTableData() {

  const sqTonnage = calculateColumnSum("sqTonnage");
  const sqTotalSets = calculateColumnSum("sqTotalSets");
  const sqTotalReps = calculateColumnSum("sqTotalReps");
  const sqIntensityAvg = calculateColumnAvg("sqIntensity");
  const sqE1rmAvg = calculateColumnAvg("sqE1RM");

  Logger.log(sqTonnage);
  Logger.log(sqTotalSets);
  Logger.log(sqTotalReps);
  Logger.log(sqIntensityAvg);
  Logger.log(sqE1rmAvg);

  return {
    e1RM: sqE1rmAvg,
    tonnage: sqTonnage,
    avgIntensity: sqIntensityAvg,
    totalSets: sqTotalSets,
    totalReps: sqTotalReps
  };

}
```

E-mailed HTML Result:
[image: HTML Table]

Comment: emails do not support JS for obvious security reasons. they also barely support CSS3 and HTML5. Your safest bet is using HTML4 with inline styles. If you want an email with dynamically filled data then you need to do it server-sided.

Comment: The script in your question seems to not have any problem. Can you further clarify the behaviour of your issue? When you say `I can't seem to place them into my table when developing in Google's environment.`? It would be better if you could share screenshots of the issue.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the information, I had no idea that was the case. To perform this server sided, would I just need to generate the HTML via a .gs file? Or possibly use scriplets per: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 thanks for the response. I have a screenshot of the current output. Essentially, when developing in Google's environment, I can't seem to get the variables placed into the table, but in my CodePen with dummy data, it seems to populate just fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

> ***NOTE**: This answer is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

In my understanding of your question, you are unable to properly populate calculated data into an HTML table when it is sent as the HTML body.

It appears that using dynamically populated HTML tables via `<script>` will not work when sending them via email as the HTML body. The HTML would need to be loaded in a web page first before the data can be populated, which is not possible in the background. With that being said, as an alternative method, you would need to dynamically modify the actual HTML source to include the HTML table data. You can refer to the sample script below to understand how to approach this:

### *Sample Script*

> A custom `buildTableHTML` function dynamically modifies the HTML source code.

```
function buildTableHTML(tableData) {

  var htmlTemplate = `<html lang="en">
                        <head>
                          <meta charset="UTF-8">
                          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                          <title>Weekly Stats</title>
                          <base target="_top">
                          <style>
                            p {
                              color: black;
                              font-size: 1.2em;
                              font-family: sans-serif;
                            }

                            .styled-table {
                              border-collapse: collapse;
                              margin: 25px 0;
                              font-size: 1.2em;
                              font-family: sans-serif;
                              color: black;
                              min-width: 400px;
                              box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                            }

                            .styled-table thead tr {
                              background-color: #32cece;
                              color: #ffffff;
                              text-align: left;
                              font-weight: bold;

                            }

                            .styled-table th,
                            .styled-table td {
                              padding: 12px 15px;
                            }

                            .styled-table tbody tr {
                              border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;

                            }

                            .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
                              background-color: #f3f3f3;
                            }

                            .styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
                              border-bottom: 5px solid #32cece;
                            }

                          </style>
                        </head>

                        <body>
                          <p>Here are your stats:</p>
                          <table class="styled-table">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Lift</th>
                                <th>e1RM</th>
                                <th>Tonnage</th>
                                <th>Avg Intensity (RPE)</th>
                                <th>Total Sets</th>
                                <th>Total Reps</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              {{placehere}}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <p>Nice job!</p>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                    `

  var placerTableRows = `<tr>{{placehere}}</tr>`

  var td = Object.values(tableData); //Load the table data into an array string
  td.unshift('Squat'); //add 'Squat' as data under 'Lift' header
  
  var tableData = td.map(data => `<td>${data}</td>`).join('');

  return htmlTemplate.replace('{{placehere}}', placerTableRows.replace('{{placehere}}', tableData))

}
```

What this function does is gather the table data as an array, place each data inside `<td>` tags, add these tags inside the `<tr>` tag, and insert that `<tr>` tag into the `htmlTemplate` by using the `replace` method to find the identifier (`{{placehere}}`) indicating where to put it.

### *Demo*

> Tested in a sample function, the HTML table is prepared to be sent as an email.

```
function sendEmailTest() {

  //Dummy data being returned by your 'emailTableData' function 
  var sampleData = {
    e1RM: 271.25,
    tonnage: 1590,
    avgIntensity: 6.5,
    totalSets: 4,
    totalReps: 7
  };

  var body = buildTableHTML(sampleData);

  // Send email test
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■',
    subject: 'send test',
    htmlBody: body
  });

}
```

> The result email message.

[image]

> ***If ever you think your question has been misinterpreted, kindly further clarify it again and include actual images of the issue and your actual desired results.***

### *Reference*

- [JavaScript String replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
- [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [JavaScript Array join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)